# ModelForm in django, how to get maxlength attribute

Tags: django

In context i have form. When I put `{{form}}` in HTML page, everything is ok.
Something like this:

```
<input id="id_sifraDrzave" maxlength="1024" name="sifraDrzave" type="text" />
```

How to get maxlength of field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it using `form.fields.username.max_length` in template.

Example (interactive shell):

```
>>> from django.forms.models import modelform_factory
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> UserForm = modelform_factory(User)
>>> form = UserForm({})
>>> print form['username']
<input id="id_username" maxlength="30" name="username" type="text" />
>>> print form.fields['username'].max_length
30

>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> print Template('{{ form.fields.username.max_length }}').render(Context({'form': form}))
30
```

Or use `<specific_column>.field.max_length`:

```
>>> print Template(
... '{% for column in form %}{{ column.field.max_length }} {% endfor %}'
... ).render(Context({'form': form}))
128     30 30 30 75
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for column in  columnMetaData%}
        alert('{{column}}');
        alert('{{column.max_length}}');
{% endfor %}
```

first alert displays:

`<input id="id_sifraDrzave" maxlength="1024" name="sifraDrzave" type="text" />`

second alert nothing...